# https:// with expression engine

Tags: solspace-freeform, low-search, expresso, low

What do i need to consider when using a ssl ceritifcate on my website. I have an sll set up on my server but at the moment i have the .hta file redirecting everyone to http://.

This is because if i visit the site over https:// there is a few things wrong.

Low Search doesnt work, 
Free Form doesnt work,
Free members - basically asks if your sure you want to login as some things might not be secure.
Control panel has no styles or javascript.

However the general website loads and operates fine.

Do i need to change some files to reflect https:// for everything to work properly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As Jarrett mentioned, as long as the `site_url` config is set to https, forms generated by EE (and its add-ons like Low Search) *will* post data over https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Low Search doesnt work, Free Form doesnt work, Free members - basically asks if your sure you want to login as some things might not be secure.

These add-ons usually use what you have configured in your "Admin > General Configuration > URL to the root directory of your site". You can also set/override the General Configuration settings using the /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file.

If using your config.php file to make the changes, you could use these basic settings to possibly fix some or all of the issues you're experiencing:

```
// check if https or http
$base_url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// set as constant
define('BASE_URL', $base_url . '/');
define('BASE_PATH'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

$config['site_url']                = BASE_URL;
$config['cp_url']                  = BASE_URL.'admin.php';

$config['theme_folder_path']       = BASE_PATH.'themes';
$config['theme_folder_url']        = BASE_URL.'themes/';
```

> Control panel has no styles or javascript.

This would be due to the /themes/ folder path setting being invalid/incorrect. You can update it using the General Configuration or config.php file I mentioned above.

> Do i need to change some files to reflect https:// for everything to work properly?

If you've configured your paths to be relative or based on the current URI, you shouldn't need to setup any special https redirect rules. However, I do recommend either forcing www or non-www for SEO and to prevent cross-domain errors. This would be done using your htaccess file:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way

Comment: I seem to have a problem with 

$config['theme_folder_path']       = BASE_PATH.'/themes';

When i look in general configuration i get BASE_URL/themes

Comment: Don't forget to add this line:

    define('BASE_PATH'. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

somewhere before the $config['theme_folder_path']

Comment: I basically copied and pasted what you wrote and everything is great. Apart from when i go to look at general config i get BASE_URLthemes 

Also the control panel works however the ssl padlock is amber not green like the front end and says that some things may be unsecure. Can you shed any light on this? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I dont have a $config['theme_folder_path'] in my config file? is this normal?
I have just added this now is that ok to do?

$config['theme_folder_path'] = '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/themes/';

Comment: Yeah it's normal. There's a long list of config variables that you can have in your config file and theme_folder_path isn't a typical config setting

Comment: Hi Jarett, Thanks for all you help, everything seems to be correct now! 
Control panel is working over https:// however although on the frontend the padlock is green. The padlock is amber in the control panel and  when  i look at the code some paths such as the /images/ path is served over http:// instead of https:// Any idea how i can change that? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, i just used REElocate and all sorted, thank you!